# Is there a way to rename bots?

Tags: chivalry-medieval-warfare

On *Chivalry Medieval Warfare* for pc; Is there a way to name or rename bots that can be played with offline? Similar to how one can rename bots on Counter Strike?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***From what I have read***, **the short answer is no**. The long answer is of course you could.. but probably not within the scope your wanting to.

---

To quote the [Chivalry: Medieval Warfare Wikia](http://chivalry.wikia.com/wiki/Chivalry:_Medieval_Warfare_Wiki) page on [creating custom games](http://chivalry.wikia.com/wiki/Create_Game):

> The Bots choose their own classes, and have randomized names.

---

I have also found a [thread on the Steam Forums](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=290569567), detailing the general console commands, and a [guide it links to](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=289867009), detailing bot-specific console commands. Neither of them offer any command that could change a bots name.

***Nitro.de*** **comments**

> I remember a function `AddNamedBot BotName[FString] bUseTeamIndex[UBOOL] TeamIndex[INT] ReturnValue[class AUTBot*]` which can be called in console but did not find anyone who was able to get this code running.

So this might be a useful command to play around with, in the console. That said, **when I do a quick Google of the command, all I get is [this forum post on steam](http://steamcommunity.com/app/219640/discussions/0/630799997412842278/)**. The asking user shares a similar username and display picture to OP, but **the question was asked over a year ago**. Regardless, there has been no response, so I would assume it is a dead end.

---

Now for the tricky way around it. **If you can find the game asset that actually contains a list of those random bot names**, you should be able to replace the names with your own names. **Always back up your saves, first**, as there is always a chance that this will instead corrupt your game.

This would only give you choice over the name options, rather then directly influencing the name of a specific bot.

If you have exactly the amount of names in the list as bots in your game, you would expect the bots to all pick a unique name, but that is just speculation. Any control on naming a specific bot past that would generally need to involve modification of the game, itself, and how it assigns the random names in the first place.

---

There are communities in place for modifying Chivalry. [Nexus Mods](http://www.nexusmods.com/chivalry/?) is but one example. If I am correct, and you can not directly change AI names, it might be a good idea to check with mod communities. Players with a greater developer understanding of the game might be able to offer an easy solution. Also keep in mind that if you end up trying to do this through modification, questions concerning the process would be considered off topic on this website.

Comment: I remember a function `AddNamedBot BotName[FString] bUseTeamIndex[UBOOL] TeamIndex[INT] ReturnValue[class AUTBot*]` which can be called in console but did not find anyone who was able to get this code running. Maybe it's worth a try to play around with it

Comment: looked into it, @Nitro.de. Interestingly enough, when you Google the exact command, there is a matching steam forum post. It looks very much like OP may have been attempting to do this for over a year and a half.

Comment: Maybe the OP should keep trying then xD

Comment: Entirely what I think, @Nitro.de, though this does remind me of Einsteins definition of insanity